# SVN Update along with checkin user

Tags: svn

When I do an svn update , I also want to print the latest author name on the same line as the file being updated. Is this possible?

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve by doing this?

Answer (score 2):

No. You would need to change the Subversion sources and compile it for yourself to do that.

What you can do is to parse the output of `svn up` and automatically look up the author for each changed file, but that's it.